Does gradle cache dependent items from local maven repositories that use file to specify the uri?
In my Android project, I use the following script in settings.gradle.kts to provide the maven repository using the local file system
repositories {
    maven { url = uri("file://${rootDir}/... /maven_repo") }
}

May I ask, does AGP cache the cache directory for the items provided in this repo? If there is a cache, how do I get AGP to use the new file without changing the version number?

It does cache the artifact even in local file system. But how can I refresh the specific artifact without changing the version?
